# How to quickly filter pandas DatetimeIndex by hour

Tags: pandas, datetime, datetimeindex

For example, I have a pandas Series as

```
rng=pd.date_range('2020-12-20',periods=1000000,freq='H')
s=pd.Series(np.random.randn(len(rng)), index=rng)
```

It is simple to select all rows belong year 2021 by

```
%timeit -n1 s['2021']
```

which is super fast, and takes only 407 µs ± 193 µs per loop

Now if I want to select all rows that is at 1 o'clock. The only way I can think of is

```
%timeit -n1 s[s.index.hour==1]
```

It is much slower, and takes 28.9 ms ± 1.06 ms per loop

I am thinking that there must be a better approach to this. Because if we use the same method to get rows belong to year 2021, that would be

```
%timeit -n1 s[s.index.year==2021]
```

it will takes 28.9 ms too.

So what is the better way to select rows by hour, minute even second?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try via [`at_time()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.at_time.html):

```
s.at_time('01:00:00')
```

**OR**

```
import datetime

s[datetime.time(1)]
#OR
s[datetime.time(1,0,0)]
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Is this the best we can do? It still takes 10.5 ms much slower than s['2021']

Comment: @user15964 updated answer...added 1 more way but I don't think there is any more faster way other than these two....It may be slower than `s['2021']` but it is approax 3 times faster than `s[s.index.hour==1]`

Comment: Thank you so much. But the new method appears to be of same speed as `at_time` on my computer

Comment: @user15964 yup both are approax same..btw If your query is solved then you can try considering accepting the answer....or If you want more fast method( I don't think there is any more faster way other than these two) then you can try considering asking another question...thanks **:)**

Answer (score 1):

Try with `between_time`

```
s.between_time('01:00:00','02:00:00',include_end=False)
```